# How can I see how many votes I have left for the day?

Tags: support, voting, top-bar

Stack Overflow updated the view (the header link).

In the past, I have seen my total votes for the day, week and remaining votes by clicking the arrow nearest to my username. But in the new look I'm unable to see my daily, weekly and monthly votes. How can see those things in the new look?

Comment: Go to the reputation league to see week and month rep

Comment: How can I see my remaining votes for the day?

Comment: @ling.s Read the duplicates... ctrl-f in those duplicates if you don't feel like reading...

Comment: @ling.s, from the dupe: `To view your vote totals for the day, week and month, go to your profile and scroll down to the “Votes Cast” box in the right-hand column.`

Comment: Bottom of your profile page, you have a "day" section in the "votes" section, you get upto 40 votes per day, so your votes left is 40 - total number of votes for the day

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Bottom of your page is there, In past look I saw that near to my profile name. Thats why asked. So I've to goto my profile and see the remaining votes?

Comment: @Flyk Bottom of your page is there, In past look I saw that near to my profile name. Thats why asked. So I've to goto my profile and see the remaining votes?

Comment: @ling.s, I don't remember seeing any *remaining* vote count, either in the popup or in my user profile. But yes, vote totals are only located in your profile now.

Comment: The only "remaining votes" notifications on SE are the ones where you approach your last view votes *while voting* and these appear next to the vote arrows *after you have voted*. You can see on [the page that used to be the activity pop up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/profile-link-stats) there there is no "remaining votes" section - only the votes that you have cast.